# Detect if Android device is no longer used by its owner

Tags: android

I need a reliable way to detect devices that are no longer used by their owners for more than a given amount of time (hours, maybe days). I initially thought about reading the motion sensor or check if the battery is being charged, but that doesn't exclude, for example, the cases when the device is stolen or the phone is lost on a boat that is constantly swinging. So, the next best thing is to detect user interaction while the screen is unlocked, basically something like this:

- run a background service which listens for OS events (through `BroadcastReceiver`)
- on each event check to see if the screen is unlocked and reset the timer
- if the timer goes off, notify a remote server and stop the background service

Now, I'm not an Android developer, and the solution I came up with is based on guesses, so I kindly ask for your feedback on the following aspects:

1. is there a better approach (easier to implement, fewer permissions, less power hungry...)? How would you do it?
2. I've read in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) that the `BroadcastReceiver` might not receive all events. Is there a way to solve this or is there an alternative component that would do the trick?
3. what events would be the best candidates for listening to?

Thanks!